# How do I convert const wchar_t* to wchar_t or a multibyte char?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need to send multibyte char to a socket after appending '\n' but what I have is a const wchar_t*. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to actually manipulate the contents of a constant, then consider [const_cast](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/const_cast).

Answer (score 0):

Appending an '\n' to a  `const wchar_t*` string means you have to make a copy of the original string. Read this MS docs on how to use swprintf for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28VS.71%29.aspx

If your problem is the conversion, the `WideCharToMultiByte` Function is your friend:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use direct newline characters to do this:

```
const wchar_t* original(L"original value");
std::wostringstream streamVal;
streamVal << original << std::endl;
const std::wstring modified(streamVal.str());
```

Going through a `_bstr_t` seems a pain but allows you to do the wide char to multibyte conversion pretty easily (small code).  Include `comsuppw.lib` in the list of libraries in your project.

```
#include "comutil.h"

_bstr_t bstrVal(modified.c_str());
const char* multibytes((const char*)bstrVal);

std::cout << multibytes;            // includes newline
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert `const wchar_t*` to `wchar_t*`?

```
reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(L"Test");
```

Should really work.

Comment: Not sure how this helps. The cast you show does nothing. Further, you need a `const_cast` to add or remove a `const` qualifier.